# Pandas table to html without header and increased font size

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to print pandas table without the column header and the increased font size.

Here's my table:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 3), columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

[image]

I was able to strip the column names:

```
display(HTML(df.to_html(header=False))
```

[image]

The last thing I needed was to increase the font size.

```
display(HTML('<font size=15>'+df.to_html(header=False)+'</font>'))
```

This code as I recall used to work for me but it appears it doesn't work anymore. I want to increase the font size of items inside all rows and as well as the pandas index. It seems I am on the right path with using html to remove the column header but I have no idea with font size. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

I did this and it worked well

```
import numpy as np
from IPython.display import HTML
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 3), columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])

DF = HTML('<font size=6'+ df.to_html(header=False)+'</font>')
```

and

```
display(DF)
```

which returned (which is really weird because there is a code error....)

[image]

Comment: Looks like the same code as my question but not working for me.